# Can I update Macmini2,1 to OS X Mavericks?

Tags: mac-mini

The title tells it all. I have an old Mac Mini2,1 which I'd like to run a software that requires at least OS X Mavericks. It possible to install that on this computer?

The detailed specifications from the 'About this Mac' section are as follows:

Hardware Overview:

Model Name: Mac mini
Model Identifier:   Macmini2,1
Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
Processor Speed:    2 GHz
Number Of Processors:   1
Total Number Of Cores:  2
L2 Cache:   4 MB
Memory: 2 GB
Bus Speed:  667 MHz
Boot ROM Version:   MM21.009A.B00
SMC Version (system):   1.19f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no.

Latest OS X that can support is Lion, 10.7.5

Ref: [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-2-duo-2.0-specs.html)

Comment: I see. Not even with dual boot?

Comment: Not with anything, that's all it can run.